# r sp/maps/maptools libraries: Map of annual solar irradiation in R

Tags: r, maps, r-sp, r-maptools

I am trying to plot annual solar irradiation data with different color on a world map. I am using R programming for the purpose.

The data I am using is from http://eosweb.larc.nasa.gov/sse/global/text/global_radiation

First, I am converting this data to a spatial dataframe and also the world map that is obtained using map(world) function to a spatial form.

I am following an example for practice from https://www.r-bloggers.com/maps-of-solar-radiation/

for plotting my code is as follows. I believe the code is completely correct but I am getting some errors

```
library(sp)
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
library(maptools)
library(RColorBrewer)

nasafile <- 'http://eosweb.larc.nasa.gov/sse/global/text/global_radiation'
nasa <- read.table(file=nasafile, skip=13, header=TRUE)

proj <- CRS('+proj=latlon +ellps=WGS84')
coords = nasa[,2:1]
datos = nasa[,3:15]
nasaSP <- SpatialPixelsDataFrame(points=coords, data=datos, proj4string=proj)

world <- map("world", plot=FALSE)

llCRS <- CRS("+proj=latlong +ellps=WGS84")
world_sp <- map2SpatialLines(world, proj4string=llCRS)

colar_sp = colorRampPalette(c("snow1", "thistle1", "plum2", "red4"))


map_sp <- list('sp.lines', world_sp)
spplot(nasaSP["Ann"], col.regions=color_sp, sp.layout=map_sp)
```

The main errors I'm getting are related to projections. I believe the way I have added them in code is correct and have seen many examples in which they have been written the same way. Please have a look at these errors and lemme know how can I make this code work.

Thanks in Advance!

Errors:

```
Error in CRS("+proj=latlon +ellps=WGS84") : 
  northings must follow eastings: +proj=latlon +ellps=WGS84

Error in checkSlotAssignment(object, name, value) : 
  assignment of an object of class “function” is not valid for slot ‘proj4string’ in an object of class “Spatial”; is(value, "CRS") is not TRUE

Error in CRS("+proj=latlong +ellps=WGS84") : 
  northings must follow eastings: +proj=latlong +ellps=WGS84

Error in initialize(value, ...) : object 'llCRS' not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two problems with your code:

1) you're using `CRS` wrongly. In `CRS("+proj=latlong...)` instead of `latlong` you must use `longlat` (see `?CRS`);

2) When you plot your map, your `color_sp` is called `colar_sp`.

---

Here is your code with the corrections:

```
library(sp)
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
library(maptools)
library(RColorBrewer)

nasafile <- 'http://eosweb.larc.nasa.gov/sse/global/text/global_radiation'
nasa <- read.table(file=nasafile, skip=13, header=TRUE)

proj <- CRS("+proj=longlat + datum=WGS84")
coords = nasa[,2:1]
datos = nasa[,3:15]
nasaSP <- SpatialPixelsDataFrame(points=coords, data=datos, proj4string=proj)

world <- map("world", plot=FALSE)

llCRS <- CRS("+proj=longlat + datum=WGS84")
world_sp <- map2SpatialLines(world, proj4string=llCRS)

color_sp = colorRampPalette(c("snow1", "thistle1", "plum2", "red4"))


map_sp <- list('sp.lines', world_sp)
spplot(nasaSP["Ann"], col.regions=color_sp, sp.layout=map_sp)
```

[image]